# Razor DropDownFor default text and value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a dropdown list in razor as,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemID, new SelectList(Model.ItemList, "Id", "ItemCodes", String.Empty), "ALL", new { @id = "ItemDetails"})
```

Here I wanted a default value which I added as 'All'. The text 'All' will be the first element, which is fine. However how can I make sure that the All has the value as '0'.

That is current Html markup is `<option value="">ALL</option>`.
I needed that as `<option value="0">ALL</option>`.

How can I add that as part of above Razor declaration.

Comment: Generally this is done in the model, not in the view.  So you would add an element to `ItemList` in the model before the view binds to it.

Comment: Thanks that was even i thought, though the project I received was having the above code, since I though instead of making that change in controller if I can find one here in the view it would be less change ;) Any was I asked this because of curiosity!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this by helper syntax instead of this You canto insert an item at 0 index like this.

```
Model.ItemList.Insert(0,new SelectListItem{Value="0",Text="ALL"});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was supposed to do this,however was wondering why to do this if there already a razor syntax for DropDownListFor. And dint wanted to change controller code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to do this:

```
 $("#ItemDetails").prepend("<option selected=selected value='0'>All</option>");
```

and ur htmlhelper will be as:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemID, new SelectList(Model.ItemList, "Id", "ItemCodes", String.Empty), new { @id = "ItemDetails"})
```